# How to install biblatex-philosophy / biber on a fresh Linux Mint 15

Tags: biblatex, installing, texlive, biber

After I tried everything to get my latex project use biblatex-philosophy I really dont know what to do any more so my question would be how is the best way to install latex on a fresh Linux Mint system to get everything to work.
I want to use biblatex-philosophy but for that dependencies did not resolve when I tried to install it via synaptic (somehow different paths) /vanilla-install (everything broke and fonts were corrupted so had to reinstall system) / aptget (backport ppas were down as they are needed to get right versions for biber and biblatex working together with texlive)

Can anyone help me here?

Do I have to delete something on the fresh installation before I begin?

Comment: To get a proper up-to-date installation of TeXLive and working `biblatex` and Biber, [vanilla TeXLive](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864) is the way to go. Did you follow the instructions in that link, and what did not work for you?

Comment: The step where one should edit "gksudo gedit etc/environment" it was already set. After reboot I tried "which tex" which didn't show anything. I am afraid that once I don't get the step complete my system is full of wrong tex stuff again..

Comment: If you `gksudo gedit etc/environment` you will see the `PATH` is already set, you just add to it.

Comment: No I mean it was already set to "PATH="/opt/texbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games""

Comment: So just skip that step? Also do I have to purge something before doing all those steps again from scratch?

Comment: You should probably delete `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/texlive/`.

Comment: If you set the `PATH`s correctly, you don't *need* to delete/uninstall anything, but you certainly can (use `apt`: `sudo apt-get purge texlive*`).  [Check](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-310003.4.1) your `PATH` settings though.

Comment: E.g., I have for TeXLive 2013 on a 64-bit machine: `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH` `MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH` `INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH`.  I put this in `~/.profile`.

Comment: ok I ran the installation until I should enter "which tex" into the terminal. But nothing will show up even after reboot. I did the "gksudo gedit etc/environment" path setting and I also have a folder /opt/textbin where all the stuff is now located. What can I do? Is the advice of @jon needed up to this point of the installation?

Comment: Confirm that you purged all previous install attempts before you tried to do this last install.  It is hard to keep track of whether you have installed from `Apt` and from `TUG` and whether you have uninstalled any of these failed attempts.

Comment: sudo rm -rf /usr/local/texlive            sudo apt-get purge texlive*                                          wget http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz
tar -xzf install-tl-unx.tar.gz
cd install-tl-..    sudo ./install-tl       sudo ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/* /opt/texbin                 gksudo gedit /etc/environment                      PATH="/opt/texbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"       which tex

Comment: also there doesn't seem to be a tlmgr in /opt/textbin/ among all the other folders and programs